# How to apply a systematic group by to a table in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

The problem is the following. I have a table in SQL Server that grows every day and I need to avoid duplicates.

I would like to apply to the table itself a

```
select 'myfields' 
from x 
group by 'myfields' 
having count(*) = 1
```

and I would like that the table will contain only the result of this query.

In any case, I must avoid to create views and to truncate the table in order to store the correct values. I know that there exist some stuff like procedures and functions but I am quite new in this field and I do not know if these objects can solve my problem.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If you don't want duplicates, why not add a unique index? If you must retain the ability to "easily" add new records while filtering out duplicates, you can create this index with the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` option. Alternatively, if modifying the data is absolutely out of the question you can create a view/views with an appropriate `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: I must avoid views, sorry for not having written that. Now I edited the question. The index part of your comment is interesting but I have a doubt about that. An index would get worse the performance of inserting new rows in the table right? The table is pretty big I should care about that

Comment: Deduplication is never free. You either pay the cost once when inserting the data, or many times over when the data is selected. Typically, the former wins out. In either case, however, an index speeds up this operation considerably.

Answer (score 0):

You should let the database ensure data integrity.  In this case, you want to ensure that you don't have duplicates across a range of columns.

There is basically one mechanism, but two ways to implement it.  You can define a unique constraint as:

```
alter table x add constraint unq_x_myfields 
    unique ( . . . );  -- list the columns here
```

This is implemented using a unique index.  Alternatively, you can define a unique index directly:

```
create unique index unq_x_myfields on x( . . . );  -- list the columns
```

These will cause the failure of any `insert` or `update` that would create a row with duplicates.  You will need to capture that error in your application if you want to report it back to the user.

It is somewhat ironic that you mention performance in a question.  Maintaining a unique index is going to be much faster than running an aggregation query on each `update` to ensure uniqueness.  There is no comparison.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot I got your point. Give me some time to see if other useful answers will come or if I will have further doubts